# Inserting variables as command options in Powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell, variables

Newb here, powershell experience is a solid 1 hour but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere so I'm starting to think it may not be the problem. I am attempting to create a script to allow me to connect to my ubuntu machine. The ip address changes with each reboot, so I created a bash script that outputs the ip address into ip.txt and im sure that is working well (no extra spaces or undesired characters).

I have created a variable that gives me the string from the file, and although the script runs successfully, the connection doesnt work. if I execute the command and manually enter the ip, it works.

```
$myip=Get-content 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\ip.txt' -Raw

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3390 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3390 connectaddress=$myiptxt
```

edit: I do not get any errors

Comment: Do you get an error (please add to the question)? What happens if you trim all the white space character s (including newlines) from the variable: `$myip = $myip.trim()`?

Comment: @iRon Thanks! your tip worked, althought I still don't know where the problem was..

Comment: This might be a typo, but in your sample code, you’re assigning to a variable called ```$myip``` but referencing ```$myiptxt``` in the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment information, the IP Address in the `ip.txt` is probably preceded and/or succeeded by one or more new line (Cr/Lf) characters.

If you use the `-Raw` parameter, [`Get-content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) will return all the lines including newline characters as a single string (`[String`]). At the other hand, if you *do not* include the `-Raw`, `Get-content` will return all the lines as separate strings (`[String[]]`), which might cause an issue in your case as well.

To remove all possible [white-space characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/white-space-characters) arround the IP Address, you might use the [`Trim()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) which *removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current string* by default:

```
$myip=Get-content 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\ip.txt' -Raw
$myip = $myip.trim()
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3390 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3390 connectaddress=$myip
```